# Pass a routing parameter to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, routes, tsx

I'd like to add a component in the my routing constant :

```
export const routes = <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
    <Route path='/counter' component={ Counter } />
    <Route path='/fetchdata' component={ FetchData } />
</Layout>;
```

**Component counter**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

    interface CounterState {
        currentCount: number;
    }

        export class Counter extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, CounterState> {
            constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) {
                super(props);
                this.state = { currentCount: 0 };
            } 
        ....
```

So I get this error message :

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/routes.tsx:10:28 
>       TS2326: Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
>     Type 'typeof Counter' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent | undefined> | ComponentClass | undefined>'.
>         Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
>           Type 'RouteComponentProps | undefined' is not assignable to type 'RouteComponentProps<{}>'.
>             Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RouteComponentProps<{}>'.

So How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code snippets.  Are your type definitions up to date?  (specifically @types/react-router)